# Unable to connect to parsoid.wmflabs.org:8080

Tags: apt, updates, update-manager

Running "sudo apt-get update" gives me:

```
W: Failed to fetch http://parsoid.wmflabs.org:8080/deb/dists/wmf-production/InRelease
W: Failed to fetch http://parsoid.wmflabs.org:8080/deb/dists/wmf-production/Release.gpg  Unable to connect to parsoid.wmflabs.org:8080:
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I've tried this several times the past two weeks.

Does anyone have any idea what could be the problem?

We use Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS.

Comment: You installed some repository, and it does not work. You can remove it.

Comment: It's about https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Parsoid. We need it so I cannot remove it. The service works okay at the moment. It's just an update I suppose.

Comment: You do not need to remove the software, you can remove the update server from the apt list. It does not work either way. Or just ignore that error message.

Comment: How do I remove the update server?

Comment: System Settings -> Software & Updates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. I removed `# deb [arch=amd64] http://parsoid.wmflabs.org:8080/deb wmf-production main` from `/etc/apt/sources.list` and now the warning has gone.